# Im trying to sum a column which based on some expression in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, expression, invoice

I have created a report (for sales Order as well as Purchase Order) which contain a lot of fields from many different tables. Every field has an expression in order to get the correct values in front of sales/purchase order e.g:

iif(isNothing(Fields!VendorInvoiceAmount.Value), Fields!CustomerInvoiceAmount.Value, Fields!VendorInvoiceAmount.Value)

The problem is if a vendor/customer have 2 different Invoices and different types of tax are applied on them.

I have the following table (just 3-4 fields to make you understand).

**SourceInvoiceNo**  -  **InvoiceAmount**  -  **SalesTaxAmount**  -  **Total**

INV-000001  -----    -   -----    1000   -----     -     -------   200      ------    -    --------      1200

INV-000002  -----    -   -----    2000   -----     -     -------   100      ------    -    --------      2300

INV-000002  -----    -   -----    2000   -----     -     -------   200      ------    -    --------      2300

AP-0001   --------    -   ------    3000   -----     -    -------   100      ------    ----    -----      3100

**GRAND TOTAL**-------------------------------------------------------**8600**

Like in INV-000002 on the same invoice amount 2 different type of taxes are applied.
the total should be 2000+100+200 = 2300. but here grand total is creating the problem.
i tried to solve this but putting this expression in Total.

Iif(Fields!SourceInvoiceNo.value = Previous(Fields!SourceInvoiceNo.value), 0 , iif(isNothing(Fields!VendorInvoiceAmount.Value), (Fields!CustomerInvoiceAmount.Value + Fields!SourceRegulateAmount), (Fields!VendorInvoiceAmount.Value + Fields!SourceRegulateAmount))

Note: Source Regulate Amount is Sales Tax Amount.
this gives the following output (which i wanted) but grand total is still the same.

**SourceInvoiceNo**  -  **InvoiceAmount**  -  **SalesTaxAmount**  -  **Total**

INV-000001  -----    -   -----    1000   -----     -     -------   200      ------    -    --------      1200

INV-000002  -----    -   -----    2000   -----     -     -------   100      ------    -    --------      2300

INV-000002  -----    -   -----    2000   -----     -     -------   200      ------    -    --------      0

AP-0001   --------    -   ------    3000   -----     -    -------   100      ------    ----    -----      3100

**GRAND TOTAL**-------------------------------------------------------**8600**

Grand total should be 6600.
In grand total i have this expression.

iif(isNothing(Fields!VendorInvoiceAmount.Value), (Fields!CustomerInvoiceAmount.Value + Fields!SourceRegulateAmount), (Fields!VendorInvoiceAmount.Value + Fields!SourceRegulateAmount)

Comment: Could you add a row_number grouped at the Invoice level to your dataset?  Then, in your totals expression, only count the InvoiceAmount+Tax when the row_number = 1, otherwise count only the Tax amounts.

Comment: Thanks very muchh =) but i have already solved that problem by dividing the invoice amount (excl tax) by the number of taxes applied on it and show it in 'total' in front of each tax.
After this method when i find the grand total it is always correct.